# How to tell rsync not to touch the destination directory permissions?

Tags: rsync

I am using rsync to sync a directory from a machine to another but I encountered the following problem: the destination directory permissions are altered.

```
rsync -ahv defaults/ root@hostname:~/
```

The problem is that in this case the permissions and ownership of the `defaults` forlder will be assigned to the destination folder.

I do want to keep the permissions for the files and subdirectories but not for the source directory itself.

Also, I do not want to remove any existing files from the destination (but to update them if needed), but I think that current settings are already ok regarding this.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to exclude the `defaults` directory from having its permissions altered, you would have to literally **not** include it in the command (since you obviously want to maintain the permissions of everything you are copying). You can thus either do this:

```
rsync -ahv defaults/* root@hostname:~/
```

Or, in case you have files or directories starting with a dot inside `defaults`, and assuming you are using bash:

```
shopt -s dotglob
rsync -ahv defaults/* root@hostname:~/
```

Comment: The downside to this is if you are using something like --delete, rsync won't try to delete remote files that are missing from the source.